# How do i start terminal in desktop

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

So in Terminal I created a new profile and I wanted it to start up to the desktop directory so I can just enter the filename I wanted to run instead of typing `cd Desktop`.

So this is what i did: **Edit** -> **Profile Preferences** -> **Title and Command** > **Run a custom command instead of my shell** and I put in the **Custom command** this `cd Desktop`. I thought if I put that then when I start the profile it will start as `john@john:~/Desktop$` instead of `john@john:~$` but when I start it I get this:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal    Profile preferences
Failed to execute child process "cd" (No such file or directory)         Relaunch
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
sh -c "cd ~/Desktop; exec bash"
```

Regarding comment:

```
sh -c "cd ~/Desktop && perl slowloris.pl -dns; exec bash"
```

Comment: Naa, it is just a simple command so marriage it out of the question. Just an upvote and accepted vote suffices :)

Comment: You're awesome dude! Do you also know how to make it to start up like this 'john@john:~/Desktop$ perl slowloris.pl -dns', i'm currently doing pentest on my website and i really need fast shortcuts like that, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to all this, i'm a windows guy that only recently moved on to Ubuntu :S i have no idea how to do that haha sorry

Comment: When i start the Terminal i want it to start up like this 'john@john:~/Desktop$ perl slowloris.pl -dns' without executing the command so i tried to do this 'sh -c "cd ~/Desktop;perl slowloris.pl -dns; exec bash" ' but it executed the command

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a noob haha

Comment: @Jester see edit ;)